# How to get information about the client that requests page from Server?

Tags: php, mysql, bash, shell, webserver

I need to get information about the client that requests a page from the server. I need to get information about client IP and which page is request? I would prefer a console application i.e. Shell or Bash script in linux[Ubuntu]. If the page is requested there would be instant print message to the console or terminal. In that message it should be included the IP address and page requested. I also wanted to save the IP address and the requested page into the database through MySQL. I'd appreciate your answer and solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I got my problem solved. Just got clue from @air4X

```
watch -n -1 'd=`date +"%d/%b/%Y:%T"`;tail -n 20 /opt/lampp/logs/access_log '
```

Thanks for great help....

Answer (score 2):

try using `watch`+`grep`+`date` on the webserver access log. In my case it is

```
watch -n -1 'd=`date +"%d/%b/%Y:%T"`;grep $d /pgms/nginx1117/logs/access.log '
```

You would have to watch out for the date format in the access log. Also the output vanishes within a second.

[Edit: use the below to extend the display to 3 seconds. again you will have to customize it for your configuration.]

```
watch -n 1 '
  d0=`date +"%S"`;
  if [ $d0 -ne 0 ]; then d1=$(printf %02d `expr $d0 - 1`); else d1=59; fi ; 
  if [ $d1 -ne 0 ]; then d2=$(printf %02d `expr $d1 - 1`); else d2=59; fi ; 
  d=`date +"%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:"`;
  grep -e "$d$d0" -e "$d$d1" -e "$d$d2" /pgms/nginx1117/logs/access.log | awk "{ print \$1,\$7 }" 
'
```

Comment: That is almost useful information I didn't want to vanish the output....It almost be there...I did like to have Like we are pinging the ip address.... Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Its quite confusing.....However Thanks for sharing a valuable information...Is there any other way to do watch the real time file operation on changes?

Comment: I have shared the answer in the bottom of the pages.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$_SERVER[]` in php.

This will give you all information of client and server you needed.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I got that regarding the php. Does it have any command for bash scripting?

Comment: I need to see real time access of the client into the console.

Answer (score 1):

For all the server variables use, you have to use `$_SERVER[]` in PHP. Yogesh Suthar is absolutely correct.

More specifically, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` contains the client IP and `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` contains the last page the browser viewed.

Answer (score 1):

Run this small PHP Script:

```
<?php
foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value){
echo '$_SERVER["'.$key.'"] = '.$value."<br />";
}
?>
```